# Why does npm install add a bunch of other packages?

Tags: gruntjs

I ran `npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev` to my local project folder and it kept adding a bunch of other node module packages. How do I make it only install the package specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM installes package dependencies recursively. So when you install `grunt-contrib-uglify` it will also [install chalk, lodash, maxmin, uri-path and, uglify-js](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/master/package.json). It will also then install any dependencies those packages have. You can't install just grunt-contrib-uglify because it wouldn't work without them.